# Access many-to-many relations of foreign object as multiple choice in model form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have model `Classroom` which relates to an instance of `Group` of the same name. I do need the Classroom model because I am not comfortable with subsetting `Group` but I need further fields on `Classroom` which I will omit below.

```py
class Classroom(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(to=Group)
    name = models.CharField()
    # ...
```

I use a model form to edit instances of `Classroom`. To this form I would like to add a MultipleChoiceField which allows the user of the form to add users to the classroom's group. I do understand that I could add a field `members` to the model form like so:

```py
class LectureClassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    members = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model = LectureClass
        fields = ["name", "is_invitation_code_active"]
```

But how can I populate this MultipleChoiceField with all users (`User.objects.all()`) and mark the ones in the group belonging to classroom (`classroom.group.user_set.all()`) as selected?

Comment: Use a `ModellMultipleChoiceField`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, thank you. That was indeed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @WillemVanOnsem, I figured out the answer.

The solution is to use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` with `queryset` to provide the options – all users in my example. Overwriting `__init()__` then allows to pass the initial data, i.e. the users in the group, by accessing the model's instance – here `LectureClass.group.user_set.all()`.

```py
class LectureClassForm(forms.ModelForm):
    members = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LectureClassForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial["members"] = self.instance.group.user_set.all()
        pass

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(LectureClassForm, self).save()
        self.instance.group.user_set.set(self.cleaned_data["members"])
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = LectureClass
        fields = ["name", "is_invitation_code_active"]
```